# How to use a CI tool in a DCVS with a central repository?

Tags: .net, mercurial, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity for Continuous Integration in my company and we use Mercurial with a central repository in the same server of TeamCity.

We set TeamCity to get the .sln (Solution File) in the central repository to build the project.

But when some developer push some change, the central repository don't update automatically. Then the TeamCity detect changes in repository and get the old version in central repository to build. The files in central repository is old until I update manually.

What workflow should I do to work with a CI tool in a DCVS with a central repository?

**Edit:**

**According to the comments. This is my TeamCity configuration:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**I discovered the problem:**

I was using the path of the central repository instead of the directory of the TeamCity Checkout.

**Solution file path:** should be: **src\BMGChip.sln** (relative to checkout directory in **C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work**)

Comment: Where do the developers push to? Is it not the central repository?

Comment: @Alan yes, but the files in central repository is old until I upgrade manually.

Comment: If your developers are pushing to the same central repository that TeamCity is watching, it will work. What do you mean by "upgrade manually"?

Comment: @jrummell sorry, "upgrade manually" means "update manually". Update to last version.

Comment: Make sure TeamCity pulls its own copy from the central repository. Don't make it build against a working copy of the central repository, that will definitely have the problem you're seeing. Instead, configure TeamCity to pull its own copy and it will update and build just fine.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ok, but TeamCity is not pulling its own copy from central repository. I'll edit the question put the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be effective, your CI should be building against wherever your developers are pushing changes to.

In addition, if you are pulling changes manually to your central repository, you should setup CI to build that branch as weel.

Not knowing the full details of how your project is structured, one way to setup CI might be:

Developers push their changesets to a shared branch on your central repository. CI is setup to watch this branch, and anytime a changeset is pushed, CI kicks off a build.

If the build is good, you can merge the branch manually to the "master" branch of your project. CI is also setup to watch that branch, and kicks off a build to verify that the merge was successful.

There are different variations on this theme--such as developers push to a feature branch, which is built, which is then automatically merged into the shared develop branch if the build is successful. The general idea is: any shared branch on your central repository should have CI setup to watch it, because, at point in time, there should be one branch that is release ready (barring any manual tests, etc).